# Cannot change Kerberos password with passwd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kerberos

I set up a common kerberos authentication for my domain. After that, it's working fine without any issues. But a user cannot change the password using Linux command. On analysis on this, I got the below error in `/var/log/auth.log`:

> bharathi passwd[3715]: pam_unix(passwd:chauthtok): authentication failure; logname=test uid=1000 euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost=  user=test

**Response from Kerberos Admin Server.**

```
May 11 16:44:48 bharathi krb5kdc[28795](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.27.50: NEEDED_PREAUTH: test@ZMEDIA.COM for kadmin/changepw@ZMEDIA.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
May 11 16:44:48 bharathi krb5kdc[28795](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.27.50: ISSUE: authtime 1368270888, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18}, test@ZMEDIA.COM for kadmin/changepw@ZMEDIA.COM
May 11 16:45:07 bharathi krb5kdc[28795](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.27.50: NEEDED_PREAUTH: test@ZMEDIA.COM for kadmin/changepw@ZMEDIA.COM, Additional pre-authentication required
May 11 16:45:07 bharathi krb5kdc[28795](info): AS_REQ (4 etypes {18 17 16 23}) 192.168.27.50: ISSUE: authtime 1368270907, etypes {rep=18 tkt=18 ses=18}, test@ZMEDIA.COM for kadmin/changepw@ZMEDIA.COM
```

Response from kerberos admin server seems to be okay. I suspect the problem might be in `pam.d` configuration.

**common-auth**

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-auth - authentication settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authentication modules that define
# the central authentication scheme for use on the system
# (e.g., /etc/shadow, LDAP, Kerberos, etc.).  The default is to use the
# traditional Unix authentication mechanisms.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

auth    sufficient  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
auth    [success=3 default=ignore]  pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure try_first_pass
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_lsass.so try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**common-account**

```
    #
# /etc/pam.d/common-account - authorization settings common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of the authorization modules that define
# the central access policy for use on the system.  The default is to
# only deny service to users whose accounts are expired in /etc/shadow.
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.
#

account required            pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
account [success=3 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_unix.so 
account [success=ok new_authtok_reqd=ok default=ignore]     pam_lsass.so unknown_ok
account [success=1 new_authtok_reqd=done default=ignore]    pam_lsass.so 
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
account requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
account required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

**common-password**

```
    #
# /etc/pam.d/common-password - password-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define the services to be
# used to change user passwords.  The default is pam_unix.

# Explanation of pam_unix options:
#
# The "sha512" option enables salted SHA512 passwords.  Without this option,
# the default is Unix crypt.  Prior releases used the option "md5".
#
# The "obscure" option replaces the old `OBSCURE_CHECKS_ENAB' option in
# login.defs.
#
# See the pam_unix manpage for other options.

# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
password    requisite           pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
password    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
password    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_lsass.so use_authtok try_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
password    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
password    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
password    optional    pam_gnome_keyring.so 
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

Your auth.log contains the following hint:

> bharathi passwd[3715]: **pam_unix**(passwd:chauthtok): authentication failure; logname=test uid=**1000** euid=0 tty= ruser= rhost= user=test

Looking at common-password the relevant lines are:

> password    **requisite**           pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000

The Kerberos-PAM-module will only handle users with uid>=1000, which is good to keep local accounts like `root` working even when the network fails.

The **requisite** marks this module as always required, so in this case *success* is stored as the result but the following modules are still executed.

> password    [success=2 default=**ignore**]  pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512

The next module is the failing *unix* module, which now tries to change the password in `/etc/shadow`. But since this is a Kerberos user, there is probably no entry in `/etc/shadow`. Due to the **ignore** this failure is ignored: the error is still logged but the result for the PAM stack is not changed.

But then the next module follows:

> password    requisite           **pam_deny.so**

This will finally overwrite the previous result code with **deny** and thus deny the request to change the password.

If it's sufficient to only change the Kerbers password, change the **requisite** for Kerberos into **[success=3 default=ignore]**, which would skip the next 3 modules (unix, lsass,deny) on success and thus continue with the **pam_permit.so**, which forces the stack to finally return success.

If on the other hand your have users with both entries in */etc/shadow* and in Kerberos, and you want to keep those two password in sync, it gets a lot more complicated to get right. Something like to following should work:

1. First try to change the Kerberos password.
2. If that succeeds, try to **optionally** also change the local Unix password in `/etc/shadow`.
3. Otherwise **`require`** the Unix password change to succeed.

   ```
   password [success=3 user_unknown=ignore default=ignore] pam_krb5.so minimum_uid=1000
   password [success=3 default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok try_first_pass sha512
   password [success=2 default=ignore] pam_lsass.so use_authtok try_first_pass
   password requisite           pam_deny.so
   password [success=ok default=ignore] pam_unix.so obscure use_authtok use_first_pass sha512
   password required            pam_permit.so
   ```